# Angular Material DatePicker Calendar Shows Behind Angular Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have the following simple code:

```
                <md-content>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="startDate" md-placeholder="Enter date">
                </md-datepicker>
                </md-content>
```

It populates fine, but when you click on it, the calendar I can see pops up in the shadow behind angular modal window.

*I'm using this datepicker:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Comment: By "modal" do you mean $mdDialog? I think posting the entire html template of your dialog will be helpful.

Comment: I'm using $uiModal, where I use a templateUrl and controller, basically another view and js file that create a modal.

Comment: I've seen a lot of answers below. But non works for @angular/material": "16.2.10" and @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "15.1.2". I spent days on this, but as a java programmer I'm quite baffled how unstable this all is. Tried amongst others: `.cdk-overlay-container mat-datepicker-content{
  z-index:1200 !important;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going into angular-material.css and changed the Z-index to 1151.

```
 .md-datepicker-calendar-pane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1151;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
          transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1); }
  .md-datepicker-calendar-pane.md-pane-open {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); }
```

Answer (score 21):

you just need to put this into the html template of the modal:

```
<style> 
.md-datepicker-calendar-pane{
z-index: 1200}
</style>
```

Comment: simple and perfect

Comment: Nice solution, working on both Angular material dialog and bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is outdated. For `@angular/material 5.0.0-rc0` have used with success:

```
.cdk-overlay-container{ z-index: 1200 !important; }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47274694/1225421

Comment: aka `.cdk-overlay-container{ z-index: 1200 !important; }`

Answer (score 3):

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1200 !important;
}
```

For Bootstrap 4 and Angular 9 material working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just like ACSteel, you can force the CSS to bring it to where you need however doing it in the module's css file isn't a good technique.

Any updates to AngularMD will overwrite your changes, you're better off forcing the CSS in your own CSS and add "!important" to the rules.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify /deep/ since this is runtime generated class:

/deep/ .cdk-overlay-container{ z-index: 1200 !important; }

Comment: You provided some CSS class but did not tell where to place it (in which file).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the component html file :

```
<style>
  ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 2000;
</style>
```