# Angular Material DatePicker Calendar Shows Behind Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, angularjs

My question is similar like this one  [Angular Material DatePicker Calendar Shows Behind Angular Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627500/angular-material-datepicker-calendar-shows-behind-angular-modal)

but my modal is bootstrap and that don't work

Comment: Your question is very unclear ..

Comment: try adjusting `z-index`

Comment: What is unclear ? I try to adjusting z-index for last 1 hours and nothing..