# angular material md-datepicker inside bootstrap modal

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, angular-material

I am tring to use Angular material  `md-datepicker` inside a Bootstrap modal but, on clicking the date the modal popup hides. How can i solve that problem?

```html
<div class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close forVideoStop" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Introduction video for body composition ...</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <md-datepicker ng-model="myDob" md-placeholder="Enter date" name="dateField" max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close forVideoStop" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Introduction video for body composition ...</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <md-datepicker ng-model="myDob" md-placeholder="Enter date" name="dateField" max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How it is...

[image: this is how it's appearing when i clicked on date]

After disabling `display: block` in the modal class...

[image: when i disabled display: block in .modal class its coming like that.]

Comment: how do you get the datepicker to render in first place? Tried lots of things just not showing the picker box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730599/4252551) to a similar question actually solved the problem. You just need to add the following style to the HTML code of your modal window:

```
<style>
    .md-datepicker-calendar-pane {
        z-index: 1200;
    }
</style>
```

The [other upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36632146/4252551) to the same question says that you can also modify the `angular-material.css` file and change the z-index there, but I don't recommend modifying the source files because your change may be reverted if you decide to update the library.

Comment: This doesn't work for material 8.1.2. The answer with ng-deep works, even with Angular 8.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer doesn't work for `@angular/material 5.0.0-rc0` .

Instead add in the `<your_component>.component.scss` file:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container{
    z-index: 1200 !important;
}
```

[::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#!#-deep-) (or [/deep/](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#!#-deep-)) prefix needs to be used because of the view encapsulation. Note that deep is marked as deprecated in the documentation and using `cdk-overlay-container` is probably not a good practice since future material module changes might break it.

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

The working solution for me with @angular/material 5.2.4 is to add my css file following part.

```
.cdk-overlay-container { 
    z-index: 1200; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The working solution for me with "@angular/material": "^11.2.13" is to add my global css file below.

`.cdk-overlay-container { z-index: 1200; }`