# Angular 5 - Bootstrap datepicker in bootstrap modal

Tags: css, angular5, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started) for datepicker. But when I use this datepicker inside modal, It opens under modal.

[image: Like this]

My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892584/angular-material-md-datepicker-inside-bootstrap-modal) . But css changes are not working for me. Any help whould be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to change the parent class style .
this will work for ngx-bootstrap calendar

follow this code
  `bs-datepicker-container, bs-daterangepicker-container { z-index: 2000; }`

Answer (score 0):

You are probaly using the wrong class if you follow that answer.

I took a look at [the github code](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-view.html) and saw that the class name used there is `bs-calendar-container`.

You might want to verify that this is the case for your wrongly z-indexed elements by inspecting them in your developer tools(F12) and verifying the class name on them.

Then you might want to change the z-index to have them appear above the modal.

The problem is caused by the modal being a direct child of the body element, and the datepicker date chooser also being a direct child of the body element, so they are competing for the same z-index space.

The bootstrap modals usually have an z-index of 1000. So setting the z-index of your datepicker item to 1200 should help, to make sure they also appear above elements that are present within the modal.

In case your datepicker has the class `bs-calendar-container` your CSS would look like this:

```
.bs-calendar-container {
    z-index: 1001;
}
```