# Angularjs Material md-datepicker within Formly template will not open calendar pane

Tags: angular-formly, angularjs-material

I'm trying to create a Formly template using md-datepicker. Unfortunately, when I click on the md-datepicker control within my form the calendar panel does not open.

[image]

controller code:

```
{
    className: 'col-xs-6',
    key: 'dateCreated',
    type: 'materialdatepicker',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Created'
    },
    expressionProperties: {
        'templateOptions.disabled': function () {
            return !vm.options.editMode;
        },
        'templateOptions.required': function () {
            return vm.options.editMode;
        }
    }
}
```

template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="materialdatepicker.html">
    <div layout="column">
        <div flex="100">
            <p class="input-group" style="display: block; margin: 0px;">
                <md-datepicker id="{{::id}}" name="{{::id}}" ng-model="model[options.key]"></md-datepicker>
            </p>
            <div class="formlyMessages" ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-if="fc.$touched">
                <div class="formlyMessage" ng-message="{{::name}}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages">
                    {{message(fc.$viewValue, fc.$modelValue, this)}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

formly config:

```
formlyConfigProvider.setType({
    name: 'materialdatepicker',
    templateUrl: 'materialdatepicker.html',
    wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
    defaultOptions: {
        ngModelAttrs: ngModelAttrs
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.materialdatepicker = {};
    }]
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the calendar panel to open. I'm not getting any errors in the console and the control does get populated with my initial value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What I forgot to mention in my original post was that this form is contained within a modal window ($uibModal). As such, the calendar pane was popping up behind my modal window.

The solution found here worked for me: [Angular Material DatePicker Calendar Shows Behind Angular Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627500/angular-material-datepicker-calendar-shows-behind-angular-modal)

You need to tell your calendar pane to open with a high z-index so it renders above the modal. Place this style sheet code into your modal html:

```
<style>
    .md-datepicker-calendar-pane {
        z-index: 1200;
    }
</style>
```

[image]