# Why angular material datepicker is showing behind the modal and in inappropriate way in angular12?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just installed latest `material` in my `angular12` app in which i have to display datepicker on the field which is inside of modal.

component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="">DOB</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [matDatepicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()">
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

style.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container mat-datepicker-content{
   z-index:20000 !important;
}
```

But the problem is that when modal is opened and when user click on input so datepicker is showing behind the modal and in inappropriate way like this.

**Note: I am using 'ngx-bootstrap' for modal popup and other components.**

How can i fix this? I

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material DatePicker Calendar Shows Behind Angular Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627500/angular-material-datepicker-calendar-shows-behind-angular-modal)

Comment: No, read my full question post. I have already tried that answer's solution but still getting this error.

Comment: `ngx-bootstrap`

Comment: yes i already tried that also. But nothing works

Comment: Please reproduce it in stackblitz

Comment: Would it be possible to add the `styles` array definition present in `angular.json` file to your question?

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh i didn't include material css in my `angular.json`  because i included material css in my `styles.scss`